# GCP cloud billing export into BQ through terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Can we automate [GCP billing export into BQ](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) through Terraform?

I tried below terraform code but it's not working. So, not sure if GCP billing exporting into BQ would be possible through Terraform or not.

```
resource "google_logging_billing_account_sink" "billing-sink" {
  name            = "billing-sink"
  description     = "Billing export"
  billing_account = "**********"
  unique_writer_identity = true
  destination = "bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/${var.project_name}/datasets/${google_bigquery_dataset.billing_export.dataset_id}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "log_writer" {
  project = var.project_name
  role    = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  member  = google_logging_billing_account_sink.billing-sink.writer_identity
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately,there is no such option. This concern is already raised under [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/4848) and this is in enhancement. Currently there is no ETA available. I can see in terraform only  [google_logging_billing_account_sink](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/logging_billing_account_sink) and Automating [logs export to BigQuery with Terraform.](https://kosyfrances.com/bigquery-logsink/)